# Remove/replace values in a list using the previous number in R

Tags: r

I am trying to replace all the zeros with the previous number from a list.

The list is something like this:

```
x <- c(3,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,3,0,0,0,1,0,2,0)
```

I tried already the function

```
x <- c(3,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,3,0,0,0,1,0,2,0)
replace (x, x==0, first(x))
[1] 3 3 3 3 3 1 3 3 3 3 3 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 1 3 2 3
```

But it changes the first value of the list =3 to all the zeros and the 2's and 1's are neglected.

Also

```
replace (x, x==0, x)
[1] 3 3 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 2 0 0 2 0 3 0 0 0 1 3 2 0
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: `library(zoo);na.locf(ifelse(x == 0, NA_real_, x))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `approx` after you `replace`d all zeros with `NA`

```
approx(replace(x, x == 0, NA),
       xout = 1:length(x), method = "constant", f = 0, rule = 2)$y
# [1] 3 3 3 3 3 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 1 1 2 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Could modify [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55204242/7128934).

```
fill = function(x){
    ave(x, cumsum(x != 0), FUN = function(y) y[pmax(1, cumsum(y != 0))])
}
fill(x)
# [1] 3 3 3 3 3 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 1 1 2 2
```